# How to determine who is retaining a UIViewController

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that is not getting deallocated even though its parent view controller is setting it to nil. When I create a new instance of it, the old one stays in memory for some reason.

What I need is a way to inspect a view controller object in memory and determine what other objects are holding a reference to it.

Possible? How?

Comment: Instruments. Always instruments.

Comment: How do you know the old one stays in memory?

Comment: @Abizem the dealloc method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

As Undo said, instruments will help you. Sometimes it can me very effective at identifying a problem, and sometimes only hints. Still, my advise is to try to understand the lifecycle of your `UIViewController` until you don't actually need it. Instruments by itself, doesn't make miracles.